# How to call value of object inside object?

Tags: java, object

simply i have this file reading it and storing it into array and then want to call the values back later to print them
my text file

> `101

12-7-2017

14-7-2017

some name

00000.. phone number

520

29-8-2017

1-9-2017

some name

00000.. phone number

1020

30-12-2017

1-1-2018

some name

00000.. phone number`

this the main test code

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner res = new Scanner (new File("reservations.txt"));
    int z=0;
    do{
    int room_numb = res.nextInt();
    String cInr=res.next();
    String cOutr=res.next();
    String Fname=res.next();
    String Lname=res.next(); 
    String phone_numb=res.next();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
    Date cIn = df.parse(cInr);
    Date cOut = df.parse(cOutr);


        Reservation.reserv[z]=new Reservation (room_numb, cIn, cOut, new Guest(Fname, Lname, phone_numb));
        z=z+1;
    }while(res.hasNext()==true);
     Guest FLnames=Reservation.reserv[0].getguest();
     System.out.println(FLnames);
}
```

my classes are these 3 
reservation

```
public class Reservation {
static Reservation[] reserv= new Reservation[200];
Guest guest;
int room_numb;
Date in, out;
public Reservation(int room_numb, Date in, Date out, Guest g) {
    this.room_numb = room_numb;
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;
    g= guest;
}
public int getroom_numb(){
    return room_numb;
}
public Date getin(){
    return in;
}public Date getout(){
    return out;
}public Guest getguest(){
    return guest;
}
```

Room

```
public class Room {




int room_numb;
String indate;

public void setRoom(int  i) {
    room_numb =i;
}
public int getRoom(){
    return room_numb;
}
```

and guest

```
public class Guest {

    String Fname;
    String Lname;
    String phone_number;

    public  Guest(String fname, String lname, String phone_numb ){
        Fname=fname;
        Lname=lname;
        this.phone_number=phone_numb;

        return;
    }
    public  String getFname(){
        return Fname;
    }
    public  String getLname(){
        return Lname;
    }
    public  String getphone_number(){
        return phone_number;
    }
```

}

i have been able to get all variables such as room numb/checkin date and checkout date/ but when ever i ask for guest through
 `Guest FLnames=Reservation.reserv[0].getguest();
     System.out.println(FLnames);`
it gives me null which mean it doesn't reference to anything 
so i am not able to use `String Fname=Reservation.reserv[0].getguest().getFname();`

**so how to get the data from guest in reservation array?**

Note: i am new to java so be gentle with ma please :) also the `sysout` is just for testing in the main method
Thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to fix your code for you.  Doing that is part of *your* homework.  However, here are a couple of hints to start you in the right direction.

Hint:  Look carefully at how your `Reservation` constructor (tries to) initialize the object's fields.   See the problem?

Hint 2:  The problem that tripped you up is that `getguest()` is returning `null` .......

---

While I have your attention, there are numerous style errors in your code, but the worst is your *complete disregard* of the Java converions for identifier names:

- A class name must start with a capital letter and be in camel-case: `Test` not `test`.
- A method or variable name must start with a lower case and be in camel-case; e.g. `getGuest` not `getguest`.
- We don't need or use "hungarian" notation in Java.  The type of a variable is expressed in the type declaration.
- Your choice of variable names is inconsistent and "uninspired".

And "numb" is what happens when your fingers get cold.

Comment: Thanks found that silly mistake in reservation
1- ok i will try to follow it since it's a simple rule
2-same and sorry :(
3-what do you mean ?
4-:)
my fingers did get numb was working in this since 3 weeks xD this is a small piece of it
Thank you.

Comment: Your `cIn` / `cOut` names look like [Hungarian Notation](http://jakewharton.com/just-say-no-to-hungarian-notation/).  If that was not your intent, then ... ignore that point.  (But typing a a few extra characters is not a good excuse for bad variable names.)